# "Connection timed out" exception from PDOException upon using findAll from ObjectRepository/Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, exception, pdo, doctrine-orm

I'm using Symfony CLI version v4.15.0 with PHP version 7.2.31.

I have created an `ObjectEntity` (+Repo), then an `ObjectEntityController`.
After I migrated to create database and table on an distant `ovh` environment (CloudDB in MySQL 5.7 , Domain with PHP global 7.2),
I upgraded my environment with the project file and tried to access the home page - this was working.

However - when I try to use method `findAll` from `ObjectEntityRepository`, I get this exception:

```
An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out
An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out
Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\
ConnectionException
in vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/AbstractMySQLDriver.php (line 93)
in vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/DBALException.php -> convertException (line 169)
in vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/DBALException.php :: wrapException (line 157)
in vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOMySql/Driver.php :: driverException (line 28)
in vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php -> connect (line 362)
in vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php -> connect (line 1449)
in vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php -> getWrappedConnection (line 892)
in vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Persisters/Entity/BasicEntityPersister.php -> executeQuery (line 889)
in vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityRepository.php -> loadAll (line 178)
in vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityRepository.php -> findBy (line 161)
EntityRepository->findAll()
in src/Controller/ObservationController.php (line 17)
     * @Route("/observation", name="observations")     */    public function index()    {        $repo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Observation::class);        $observations = $repo->findAll();        return $this->render('observation/index.html.twig', [            "observations" => $observations        ]);    }}
in vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php -> index (line 157)
in vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php -> handleRaw (line 79)
in vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php -> handle (line 191)
Kernel->handle(object(Request))
in public/index.php (line 25)
```

`Pdo_mysql` was enabled in my project like this:

```
PDO Driver for MySQL => enabled
Client API version => mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407
```

Could someone can help me? Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Use the following command before findAll()

```
 .....
    ini_set('max_execution_time', '0');
```